# In C, how to access to an array of pointers (passed as parameter)

Tags: c, arrays, list, pointers

I'm a beginner (in C) trying to code a simple automaton. I have an array `automaton[]` of 50 pointers to structures of `lTransitions` type. I want to call `addTransition(&automaton, s1, &t)` to add a transition to the list (`t` points to structure just created with `malloc()` ...). If `automaton[state1]` is `NULL` then I need to replace it with the address that `t` points at. Otherwise, I need to follow the chain until `automaton[state1]->next` is `NULL`.

The problem is that the test always returns false because `*(automaton+e1)` is the address of the pointer not the structure to which it should point (or NULL if none).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here are the critical lines of my code:

```
struct lTransitions { char   c;
                      int    stateNext;
                      struct lTransition *next };

struct lTransitions *automaton[50]=NULL;

void addTransition( struct lTransition **automaton, int state1, struct lTransition *t){
...
if (*(automaton+e1)==NULL) { *(automaton+e1) = t; }
    else { ... }
```

Comment: `struct lTransitions *automaton[50]=NULL;` typo as `struct lTransitions *automaton[50] = { NULL };`

Comment: Don't use `*(automaton+e1)`, use `automaton[e1]` instead.  It's much more readable.

Comment: Thank Bachman but it doesn't work either because automaton is a pointer to a pointer (in an array).*(automaton+e1) is the right address of the pointer in the array but I cannont figure out how to read the value at this memory address.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're passing the addess of the whole array and not the array, you can't access its elements, you need to dereference it before you can access the elements:

```
if (*((*automaton)+e1)==NULL) ...
```

Or write it in a better way:

```
if ((*automaton)[e1] == NULL) {
    (*automaton)[e1] = t;
}
```

automaton is the pointer to array, (*automaton) is the array.

This code correctness depends on the way that you call the function, though, and you have cut it from you example. Next time write a complete example.

Comment: Thank you hdante. The compiler (Code:Blocks IDE) issues an error for both writings of the if statement: "error: invalid operand to binary == (have 'struct lTransitions' and 'void''). I call the function by: addTransition(&automaton, s1, &t)

Comment: hdante, you're right. I checked that (*automate)[e1] correctly returns NULL.

Comment: ... I can printf the address and the value pointed at but the test ==NULL doesn't compile anyway.